# I am trying to get all users from google workspace using python but I am getting a HTTP error with code 400 after making the API call

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, frappe

I am trying to get all users from google workspace using python but I am getting this error message as a response " "exception": "googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&query=isSuspended%3DFalse&maxResults=100&orderBy=email&viewType=admin_view&projection=basic&showDeleted=False&alt=json returned "Invalid Input". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Input', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]">" ".Below is my code;

```
import frappe
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']
SUBJECT = 'workspace_email'
CUSTOMER_ID = 'my_customer'

@frappe.whitelist(allow_guest=True)
def main():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'path_to_my_config.json', scopes=SCOPES
    )
    credentials = credentials.with_subject(SUBJECT)
    admin = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
    results = admin.users().list(
        customer=CUSTOMER_ID,
        query='isSuspended=False',
        maxResults=100,
        orderBy='email',
        viewType='admin_view',
        projection='basic',
        showDeleted=False,
    ).execute()
    print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried regenerating a new service key and assigning the following roles to my principal
i.e "
Owner,
Service Account Admin,
Service Account Token Creator,
Service Account User
"

Is there something I'm missing or not doing correct?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?